# Why can't the mongodb driver handle $elemMatch or any embedded queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use [mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) 3.5 for node.js.

Whenever I want to search embedded fields like this:

```
SomeCollection.findOne({someObject: {embeddedField: thisString}})
```

or use $elemMatch similarly:

```
SomeCollection.findOne({someArrayOfObjects: {$elemMatch: {someField: thisString}}})
```

it simply doesn't work. I have to use dot notation in the former example, and nothing (so far as I know) will help me in the latter example.

What's the meaning of this behavior? Why doesn't such basic features work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works exactly as intended, you just need to learn the query language.

The first query searches for documents where "someObject" is `{embeddedField: thisString}` precisely, i.e. no other fields in the subdocument.

To search documents where "someObject" **has** a field "embeddedField" with specific value `thisString` regardless of other fields in the subdocument you use dot notation. It's a simple and quite elegant solution to distinguish between the 2 queries. I admit it's not intuitive and does require a bit of reading tho.

Same applies to the $elemMatch.